# Use of the (das & der) in an advertisement

Tags: translation, sentence-structure, conjugation

So I'm doing this fictional ad for my German 1 class and I'm unsure about my accuracy in sentence structure.

What I have written:

> Der sportfilm! Es kostet €4. Das ist billig.

Now I would assume as of what I learned about conjugation that I would change es and das to er and der but just going off of other worksheets I have confused myself a bit.

Comment: I know it's a fictional ad, but would you really say something like that in English? (The sports movie. It costs €4. That's cheap.) Also note that _Sportfilm_ as a noun would have to start with a capital S.

Comment: @Ingmar You cannot compare English and German here anyway. Anyhow, I would even shorten it to "Der Sportfilm. Nur 4€. Das ist billig."

Comment: You would? I agree with "nur x €", it's common enough, but I don't think "das ist billig" would go well with any advertisement in either German or English. German "billig" has the exact same (negative) connotations as the English "cheap".

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is not part of the question I'd like to point out that "Sportfilm" is a noun and therefore has to be written in uppercase.

Now regarding your claim:

If you refer to the movie itself it should be "Er" and "Der" as Martin Peters wrote. But referring to the movie using "der" is kind of clumsy.

If you instead vaguely refer to the action of purchasing the movie "Es" and "Das" would be ok.

A middle ground would be "Der Sportfilm! Er kostet 4€. Das ist billig." Like this you would directly refer to the movie as an entity in the second sentence while referring to the fact that its cheap in the third.

Let me give you another example.

"The woman. She is beautiful. She is nice." would translate to "Die Frau. Sie ist schön. Sie ist nett."

Instead "The woman. She is beautiful. That is nice." would translate to "Die Frau. Sie ist schön. Das ist nett."

I hope this helps clarifying the difference.

Answer (score 0):

"Er" is correct, since it is "der Film".

Comment: Please extend your answer to fully address the question. As it stands now it only comments on the gender issue regarding *Film* - but there is more to say here.